# INameCreationService - how to send a parameter

Tags: c#, .net, desktop

I have a desktop application which uses IDesignerHost & implements drag & drop of controls. This is based on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163634.aspx example.

I implemented INameCreationService & in CreateName method, I am displaying a dialog to accept control name. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/91265/UserControl-Prompts-for-ControlName-after-Drop-in.

Now the question is whenever the user does copy-paste, EnterControlNameDialog pops-up. When the user copies a set of controls (say a groupbox which has 5 inner controls), then EnterControlNameDialog is displayed 6 times.

I would like to display EnterControlNameDialog only when new controls are created via Toolbox drag-drop. During Copy-Paste, I want to create the controls automatically without showing this popup.

Is this possible?